# How to migrate from SourceGear Vault to TFS?

Tags: tfs, sourcegear-vault, tfs-migration

Is there any easy way of migrate files version from SourceGear Vault to TFS?

Answer (score 5):

Not really. TFS isn't too good about importing history.

On the plus side, this is your chance to rearrange your source code tree.

Answer (score 1):

MS have created a [toolkit](http://migrationsynctoolkit.codeplex.com/) for creating import and export tools.

But a [quick search](http://www.google.com/search?q=tfs+vault+import&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a) doesn't show (in the first few hits) anyone who has done the hard work.

Another option is to import current state (just perform a TF add into an Import branch ad then branch into your working project), and keep Vault around for when you need to look at history.

Comment: Note: since this 2009 answer, Microsoft writes, "TFS Integration Platform was designed to work with Team Foundation Server 2012 and earlier. Use of these integration tools with TFS 2013 and 2015 may cause errors. TFS Integration Platform will not be supported past May 31, 2016...This project, issues and discussions are no longer tracked. Please use the MSDN forum instead: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?forum=tfsintegration "

Answer (score 0):

In my experience there is only a 'hard way'.
I migrated all of the source code in my company from Vault 7 to Team Foundation Version Control 2015 through Git.
So the short answer is 'no'.

If anyone is interested in a non-easy way, 
we migrated from Vault to Git to TFVC by using
https://github.com/tomaskovarik/chalk
and
https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs