# How to migrate from SourceGear Fortress 1.1.x to TFS 2010?

Tags: version-control, version-control-migration, sourcegear-fortress

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583331/how-to-migrate-from-sourcegear-vault-to-tfs) but it was only similar and, more importantly, dated by over a year. I'm hoping there is something I can't find out there and that is better than what that answer points to.

Requirements:

- Preserve source code history (even if only loosely via text only since all of our prior users may not be created in the TFS repository)
- Preserve our item tracking history (again, even if just loosely since Fortress wasn't all that great about this). Ultimately, I want some searchable history of what we have done in the past and why. I don't necessarily need all of the hooks in place tying work items to source code or anything like that, but I do need discussions and decisions associated with the work items kept around.

Comment: Rolled back the change. I very intentionally am flagging this as `tfs2010` and not just `tfs` because I don't care about any version of TFS other than 2010. I realize that there are more posts using the `tfs` flag than the `tfs2010` flag but I don't care - this is version-specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're taking the plunge and just losing all of our history. I absolutely HATE this decision but we simply cannot find anything better and don't have the time to implement anything custom. :-(